# Share Qt Widget with pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a QMainWindow class with a Stacked Layout. This layout holds three different QWidgets.

I would like to share QTextEdit widget amongst all three QWidgets. What is the best way to do it?

I have tried to use a parent class and make QTextWidget static, but had no luck.

Comment: Move it to the parent widget's layout when the stack index changes.

Comment: A possible solution is to not include the common `QTextEdit` in your three `QWidgets`, but add one `QTextEdit` to your `QMainWindow`.